# Problem with a system of equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, roots, sagemath, common-root

What is the solution of these equations

$\begin{align}a1 - 2*b1*b3 - b2^2 - b4^2 - 2*b5*b6=0 \\
a2=0 \\
a3 - b3^2=0 \\
a4 - 2*b3*b4 - b6^2=0 \\
a5=0 \\
a6=0 \\
b1^2=0 \\
b1*b2=0 \\
b1*b4 + 1/2*b5^2=0 \\
b1*b5=0 \\
b1*b6 + b2*b5 + b4*b5=0 \\
b2^2*b5=0 \\
b2*b3=0 \\
b2*b4=0 \\
b2*b5^2=0 \\
b2*b6 + b3*b5 + b4*b6=0 \\
b3^2*b5=0 \\
b3*b4*b5=0 \\
b3*b6=0 \\
b4^2*b5=0 \\
b4^2*b6=0 \\
b4*b5^2=0 \\
b5^3=0 \\
b5^2*b6=0
\end{align}$

Now my question is for:

1. $b3 \neq 0$ What I am getting directly from this equation is $b1=b2=b5=b6=0=a2=a5=a6$ and $a1=b4^2$ and $a4=2b3b4$.

Now in the solution of sage I am getting $b4=0$ as well. But why? I am trying for an hour and couldn't figure it out! I hope that there is some hidden equation which is not very clear but what is the general way to find it out. If we don't want to use any computational tool.

2. Same case when $b6 \neq 0$. I can't find why $b2=0$. Please give me a way to figure this calculation out as well.

Comment: it is too difficult for me to read your equations, at least a new equation should start in a new line, and it is not mach work to eliminate some =

Comment: @NoChance $==$ means "equal to". This is simple algebra question

Comment: I am not trying to be silly, if "==" has no meaning, why use it instead of "="? Also some basic reductions you could perform to make the problem manageable. for example $b1^2=0$ leads to $b1=0$ leads to $b2=0$, $b5=0$ etc. try to do this first.

Comment: I actually copy pasted it from Sage.

Comment: $b4=0$ because $b2=0$ because $b1^2=0$.

Comment: This is a good exercise to train your mind in searching for clues and details and joining both. For example $b1*b2=0$ means a) $b1=0$ or b) $b2=0$ or c) both are $0$. Then you look for other formulas which you can relate to only one of the above choices. Better than any software.

Comment: @NoChance $b2=0=b1$ but why $b4=0$. What is the relation in between $b2$ and $b4$?

Comment: @Ripi2 Could you please explain why $b4=0$? I know the statement you made...

Comment: You have an equation $b1*b2=0$ and you know that $b1=0$ so $b2$ is zero. You have an equation $b2*b4=0$. Since $b2=0$ then $b4=0$.

Comment: Why $b1=0$ imply $b2=0$. Suppose $b2=3, b1=0$ then $b1*b2=0$??

Comment: @NoChance Same with the second one!!

Comment: There are too many equations. Reduce the number by replacing easily known values, as $a2=a5=a6=b1=b5=0$. Then dismiss not-informative results, as $0·b2=0$ Anyhow, it seems to me the resulting equations are not enough to solve them all.

Comment: Hi, I did that, let me update more of my work.

Comment: I reduced everything and you can see that I wrote your observations as well but could not get why $b4=0$ but if you check in Sage they will give you $b4=0$.

Comment: I guess Sage found a solution, not all the solutions. Also, post the reduced system.

Comment: Hi, no sage actually giving me a general solution. I haven't reduced the system because I am in kind of dilemma whether I am kiling some info or not!! If you want you can edit